# How to write a query that returns the id of the managers in the department of which no more than 5 people work?(postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to write a query that returns the id of the managers in the department of which no more than 5 people work?

I have a data table **employee**

**id integer** - id employee

**name char** - name employee

**department_id integer** - id of the department in which the employee works

**chief_flg boolean** - flag that the employee is in a leadership position

**birth_dt date** - Date of Birth

**salary integer** - employee salary

I tried to write query like this (postgreSQL)
but I think you can do something through HAVING

```
SELECT COUNT(e.id)<5, e.id as id_column
FROM employee AS e
WHERE chief_flg = 'True'
GROUP BY e.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query, no need for having:

```sql
select e.* from 
FROM employee AS e
join (SELECT COUNT(*), e.department_id
        FROM employee AS e
        WHERE chief_flg = 'True'
        GROUP BY e.department_id) mng
    on (mng.department_id = e.department_id and mng.cc <= 5)
WHERE chief_flg = 'True'
```

Rather join with inner select, that counts number of employees in departments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of doing this. One method to consider is:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM employee c INNER JOIN employee e
  ON c.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE c.chief_flag = True
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
```

The basic idea is to join the chiefs (`c.chief_flag = True`) to all the employees in the same department (`c.department_id = e.department_id`). As you suggested, you can then use `HAVING COUNT(e.id) <= 5` to limit to the departments with 5 or fewer employees.

An alternative that might be easier to follow (although is possibly less performant):

```
SELECT c.id
FROM employee c
WHERE chief_flag = True
 AND (SELECT count(*) FROM employee e WHERE e.department_id = c.department_id) <= 5
```

This gets all rows with `chief_flag = True` and checks whether the number of employees in their department is 5 or fewer.

Another option is something like:

```
SELECT id
(
 SELECT id, chief_flag, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) dep_count
 FROM employee
) mt
WHERE chief_flag = True AND dep_count <= 5
```

This is similar to the other answer on this question (calculates the number of employees in each department) but uses a window function in a subquery to do so.

Your existing attempt will not work (even if you clean up the syntax) since you are only looking at the table once and limiting to `chief_flg = 'True'`. Once you've limited the query to only consider chiefs, you have no way of counting the other employees. That's why most solutions to this would either join, use a subquery, or use a window function.